# How to draw special line bar chart (refer to my picture) in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, html

I am working on iOS and finding some open source libraries can draw a graph like this.

[image: my chart]

I need to add 2 line chart and a bar chart between the points of these 2 line. Is there any library can do it?
If no, is there any js library can draw this?

Comment: It would be great if the graph is interactive. i.e. custom action when i click a point in the chart

Answer (score 1):

[JBChartView](https://github.com/Jawbone/JBChartView) should do the trick for you. 
You might have to do some customization to do the different actions.